# Problem with C# equivalent of Java Unsigned right bit-shift operator

Tags: java, c#

I'm attempted to port some code over from Java to C#. In Java I have the following method:

```
public static int eval(long hand) {
        final int c = (int)hand & 0x1FFF;
        final int d = ((int)hand >>> 13) & 0x1FFF;
        final int h = (int)(hand >>> 26) & 0x1FFF;
        final int s = (int)(hand >>> 39);
        ...
}
```

Calling this method with hand = 1649468792833 gives c=1, d=3, h=3, s=3.

My C# version is:

```
public static int eval(long hand) {
            int c = (int)hand & 0x1FFF;
            int d = (int)((uint)hand >> 13) & 0x1FFF;
            int h = (int)((uint)hand >> 26) & 0x1FFF;
            int s = (int)((uint)hand >> 39);
            ...
}
```

This outputs c=1, d=3, h=3, s=1573056.

I don't really understand what the >>> operator does in Java but I read that casting to uint and using >> should be equivalent in C#.
Can anybody understand why I'm getting this erroneous large value for s in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Java code, you're using the `>>>` operator on a 64-bit integer - in your C# code, you're using it on a 32-bit integer.

The reason you're getting the rather large value for `s` (instead of just 0, as you might expect if you shifted a 32-bit integer right by more than 32 bits) is that when you use `>> 39` on a 32-bit integer, it *actually* performs a `>> 7`, which is odd but is in line with the [specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v6/standard/expressions.md#1210-shift-operators):

> When the type of `x` is `int` or `uint`, the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of count. In other words, the shift count is computed from count & 0x1F.

I would suggest casting (once) to a `ulong`, and doing all the shift operations on that:

```cs
ulong uhand = (ulong) hand;
int c = (int)hand & 0x1FFF;
int d = (int)(uhand >> 13) & 0x1FFF;
int h = (int)(uhand >> 26) & 0x1FFF;
int s = (int)(uhand >> 39);
```

That gives you the results you expect.

Comment: @Franck: Yes, I suspect this was for compatibility with other languages, but I do wonder whether the designers now regret that decision.